# Highcharts Scaling Graph Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create a chart:

http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/sixthiteration/home.php

When scaling however, it seems to chop part of the right side of the chart off...I'm not entirely sure why..?

Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'summarycontainer',
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
       title: {
        text: 'No. Entries Submitted This Month',
        style: {
             fontSize: 10
        }
      },      
      xAxis: {         
         lineWidth: 1,
         lineColor: '#999999',
         title: {
            text: 'x-axis' 
         }
      },
      yAxis: {
         title: {
            text: 'y-axis'
         },
     labels: {
        y: 2
     },
     lineWidth: 1,
         lineColor: '#999999',
         gridLineWidth: 1,
         gridLineColor: '#eaeaea', 
         startOnTick: false,
         showFirstLabel: false
      },
      tooltip: {
         shared: true               
      },
      legend: {
         enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
      },
      series: [{
         type: 'scatter',
         name: '',
         data: [10, 20, 10, 20, 2, 3, 1, 9],
         lineColor:  '#f6a828',
         color: '#418ed6'
      }],
   });
});
```

And in my HTML, I have a div container:

```
<div id = "summarycontainer" style="width: 250px; height: 250px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In code above you have:

```
data: [10, 20, 10, 20, 2, 3, 1, 9],
```

and in source of page thre is:

```
data: [10, 20, 10, 20, 2, 3, 1],
```

Maybe that you think the plot chops last dot?

**edit:**
Add:  `categories: ['', '']` to your `xAxis` :

```
xAxis: {         
         categories: ['', ''],
         lineWidth: 1,
         lineColor: '#999999',
         title: {
            text: 'x-axis' 
         }
      },
```

In my opinion there is a bug in highcharts.

**edit 2:**

For formatting tooltip use (below is only example!):

```
tooltip: {
         formatter: function() {
                   return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
               this.x +': '+ this.y +'Â°C';
         }
      },
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. So I added your suggestion and it does stop the graph from chopping the last point off but it blanks my tooltip for the first two points? Regarding the page source, I was messing with the code - that isn't the error.